# Not able to update table on jsp using Json

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to fetch data from db using Json but not getting my mistake.After clicking on the "Show Table" button only the Alert appears and No Table is displayed:

MyJsp.jsp

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("#emptable").hide();

        $("#showTable").click(function(event){

            $.get('EmpServlet',function(responseJson){

                if(responseJson!=null){
                    $("#emptable").find("tr:gt(0)").remove();
                    var table1= $("#countrytable");
                    $.each(responseJson,function(key,value){

                        var rowNew = $("<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>");
                        rowNew.children().eq(0).text(value['eid']);
                        rowNew.children().eq(1).text(value['ename']);
                        rowNew.children().eq(2).text(value['esal']);
                        rowNew.appendTo(table1);

                    });
                }

            });

         $("#tablediv").show();   
            alert('hhh');
        });

    });

</script>
<body class="container">
<h1>AJAX Retrieve Data from Database in Servlet and JSP using JSONArray</h1>
<input type="button" value="Show Table" id="showTable"/>
<div id="tablediv">
<table cellspacing="0" id="emptable"> 
    <tr> 
        <th scope="col">ID</th> 
        <th scope="col">Name</th> 
        <th scope="col">Salary</th> 
     </tr> 
</table>
</div>
</body>
```

Here i am getting the "alert as hhh" that means that it is executing without any error.

Servlet:  'EmpServlet' contains

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        ArrayList<Employee> al=new ArrayList<Employee>();

        EmployeeDetails obj=new EmployeeDetails();
        al=obj.getDetails();

        System.out.println("-----------hiii-----");
        Gson gson=new Gson();

        JsonElement element=gson.toJsonTree(al,new TypeToken<List<Employee>>() {}.getType());

        JsonArray jsonArray = element.getAsJsonArray();
        response.setContentType("application/json");
        response.getWriter().print(jsonArray);

    }
```

I am able to see "hii" on console and values are fetched from db.Please help !!

Also,please explain me meaning of below code  :

```
$("#emptable").find("tr:gt(0)").remove();
```

AND

```
rowNew.children().eq(0).text(value['eid']);
rowNew.children().eq(1).text(value['ename']);
rowNew.children().eq(2).text(value['esal']);
```

Is this "eid" the same as the pojo class of Employee  where i have decleared :

```
String eid;
String ename;
String esal;

public Employee(String eid, String ename, String esal) {
    super();
    this.eid = eid;
    this.ename = ename;
    this.esal = esal;
}

public String getEid() {
    return eid;
}

public String getEname() {
    return ename;
}

public String getEsal() {
    return esal;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at this:

```
$.get('EmpServlet',function(responseJson){
    $.each(responseJson,function(key,value){
        ...
    });
});
```

You always get one JSON object as a response. It means, the `each`-cycle happens only once, if ever. In the `value` argument is going to be the actual array.

I have not tested it though, so maybe i'm wrong.